# fsck error on boot: /dev/sda2 - can't type slash character

Tags: boot, command-line, 18.04, initramfs

I need to set the fsck manually on boot but I can't type in the character **/** that is required to set the path.

```
(initramfs) fsck /dev/sda2
```

I tried multiple keyboard combinations without success.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such cases it's useful to have a look at the US keyboard layout.

[image: US Keyboard layout]

The key on your keyboard to the left of the right Shift key should be / on US keyboards - which is the default unless changed on Linux.

It's also possible to do this without ever typing `/`. Simply `cd ..` until you are at `/`, then `cd dev` followed by `fsck sda2`. You don't need to give it the full path.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt answer and the "cd" tip. Got it to work.

Comment: Great :) Happy to be of assistance :)